# Proof That a Linear Map is a Subspace With Certain Givens

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

If I say there is a linear map **T** ∈ L(V,W) where L(V,W) is the space of all linear maps from V to W. Also, say that U is a subspace of V. I'd like to show that T(U) is a subspace of W, but I'm not entirely sure how I can illustrate such a point. I'm even more unsure how to do so in sufficiently formal language.

Attempting to illustrate this, I might say that because T(U) maps to the co-domain W, this means that it is a subspace of W. I believe this is not really a proof though.

Comment: You basically want to see that for $T':U \longrightarrow W, Im(T')$ is a subspace of $W$, where $T'$ is the restriction of $T$ to $U$.This is not too hard, think about how this linear transformation acts on a basis of $V$ and then how does it acts on a basis for $U$, and what do you actually need for a set to be a vector space, also it must be clear that for all $u \in U, T(u) \in W$.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I am trying to prove it without the direct invocation of the basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show 2 things

1. $0\in T(U)$
2. $w_1,w_2\in T(U)$ implies $aw_1+bw_2\in T(U)$ for all scalars $a,b$.

1 is immediate because $T(0)=0$. For 2, write $w_1=T(v_1)$ and $w_2=T(v_2)$ where $v_1,v_2\in U$. Because $U$ is a subspace, $av_1+bv_2\in U$. So by the linearity of $T$:
$$
aw_1+bw_2=aT(v_1)+bT(v_2)=T(av_1+bv_2)\in T.
$$
This gives you 2.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Elements of $T(U)$ can be written as $T(x)$ for some $x \in U$.  Can you show that

- adding two elements in $T(U)$ gives you another
- multiplying any element in $T(U)$ by a scalar gives you another

If so, then you've shown that $T(U)$ is a subspace of $V$.